# Product Quantity in woocommerce widget Cart

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to have a quantity field on my product listing archive on single product page. It works fine, but not with product archive listing.

Here are the scenario:

— default Quantity is 1 
— I change it to 2
— add this product to cart 
— Quantity in the cart is 2
— change that quantity to any i.e: 5
— add same product to cart again
— Quantity in the cart increased by.. 2! not adding 5 
(even though [data-quantity] attribute is changed correctly)
— so now Quanity is 4 instead of 7 increased by 5

I tried it on fresh install of wordpress and using twenty sixteen themes and deactivated all plugins. Here are my code that I used, is there any additional filter to do this on product listing archive?

```
function custom_quantity_field_archive() {

    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product->product_type && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_quantity_field_archive', 31);


/**
 * Add requires JavaScript. uzzyraja.com/sourcecodes/
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler() {

    wc_enqueue_js( '
        jQuery( ".post-type-archive-product" ).on( "change input", ".quantity .qty", function() {
            var add_to_cart_button = jQuery( this ).parents( ".product" ).find( ".add_to_cart_button" );

            // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.attr( "data-quantity", jQuery( this ).val() );

            // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.attr( "href", "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart_button.attr( "data-product_id" ) + "&quantity=" + jQuery( this ).val() );
        });
    ' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler' );
```